Cut Riemann surface along Cycles and integrate one form on it
In Bobenko's lecture notes on Riemann surface https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~bobenko/Lehre/Skripte/RS.pdf on pp35-36, he proved Riemann's bilinear identity. The first in the proof he "cut along Riemann surface along a homology basis" and made it to a simply connected domain $F_g$ with boundary (suppose the Riemann surface has genus $g$). Then, he convert the integration of a 1 form $\omega$ on the Riemann surface $R$ to the simply connected $F_g$ (a 4g-gon model). I don't understand what this step exactly means. Especially, in such a 4g-gon model, he used that for the identified two points $p,p'$ in two sides of this 4g-gon, $\omega(p)=\omega(p')$. But for such a point exactly on a certain cycle, then in $F_g$, which piece does this point belong to? If we do integration on $F_g$, then $p,p'$ are not even points in $F_g$.
Also, according to eq.(57), if we define a function
$$
f(q):=\int_{P_0}^q\omega
$$
then eq.(57) means $f(p)=f(p')=-B_j$ (or with positive sign, it doesn't matter). But why we can't use the same argument for $\omega(p)=\omega(p')$ to say that $f(p)=f(p')$?
I'm very confused about such operation, thanks for any help.
